# Password incorrect when using SSH with public/private key

Tags: linux, ssh, password, key-authentication, kubuntu

I enabled logging to my remote Kubuntu computer with a public/private key following this short [tutorial](https://debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password), and now logging is easy and doesn't ask for password.

Anyway, I noticed when I try to sudo, I'm asked for a password and when entered it says it's incorrect. And since I cannot sudo, I cannot modify the sshd_config or other root files.

I even cannot login to the physical machine using my own password, so all in all, I'm stuck.

How do I enable back the password authentication? (knowing that I cannot use sudo now) Thanks.

Comment: Just to cover the basics, when using `sudo`, are you entering _your_ password (the correct answer), or the _root_ password (the incorrect answer)?

Comment: I enter my user password (I don't even know the root password). This is the output in the console:

[sudo] password for <my-username>: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the tutorial is this:

> At this point, user’s account on the server can be locked for password authentication. On Linux systems, one can make:
>
> ```
> root@apanela.com:~# passwd -l ornellas
> ```

So, if you followed this part of the tutorial you've locked your password. The only way to resolve this is either to use a root account to unlock your password, or boot with a rescue disk and fix up the `passwd`/`shadow` file directly:

```
passwd -u ornellas
```

Comment: Since I don't know the root password, I guess I'm only left with the second option, to boot with a rescue disk. @roaima can I use the Kubuntu installation cd for this purpose? Please explain how it's done briefly. Tnx